# Drools upgrade version from 6.x to 7.x

Tags: version, drools

In 7.16 version .drl generated from excel sheet is corrupted one. In action column of xls sheet if else conditions there and are written in new lines of single column.... So when generating drl file instead of printing conditions in new line.... Its printing \n character. Can anyone help on this?